# How to show all data in a variable array foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a data in array and use foreach to show all data in array and then i make a variable in foreach.

I Have an array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 2 
    [1] => 36 
)
```

```php
$data = Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 36 );

foreach ($data as $hasil) {
    $allData = $hasil;
}

$array = array(
    'allData' => $allData,
);

print_r($array);
```

The Output is

```
Array ( 
    [allData] => 36 
)
```

But, i want my output is

```
Array ( 
    [allData] => 2,36 
)
```

What should i'll code for output that?

Comment: So you want all the data to be in one element, separated by commas? Can I ask why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join your array values by comma and then pass these values to value of your new array:

```
<?php
$data = [2, 36];
$joinedData = implode(',', $data);

$array = array(
 'allData' => $joinedData,
);

print_r($array);
```

or:

```
<?php
$data = [2, 36];

$array = array(
 'allData' => implode(',', $data),
);

print_r($array);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [allData] => 2,36 )
```

Comment: @GentaHaetamiPutra Glad to hear it, you can upvote this and other answers, also, if they answered your question : ))

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach will overwrite the element `$allData` for each iteration, so it will in effect only get the last element in the array.

You can use `implode()` instead, with the glue of `,`.

```php
$data = array(2, 36);
$allData = array(implode(",", $data));
// echo $allData[0];
```

Or if you don't need it as an array, just the string directly,

```php
$data = array(2, 36);
$allData = implode(",", $data);
// echo $allData;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php),

```
$data = Array ( 0 => 2, 1 => 36 );
$array['allData'] = implode(",", $data);
print_r($array);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/iYm2u),

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [allData] => 2,36
)
```